# How do I position a <div> element after another class or div which isn't accessible to me

Tags: html, css, wordpress

So the issue I am facing is that for my blog post's page, I want the raw html that I have specifically inserted at the bottom to appear after the social media icons.

The link for the same is - [My post page](http://chevaun.com/blog/creative-freedom/)

So I want the "enter your email and singup section" to appear after the social media icons **when the page is loaded**. 
Just to be clear I am not able to modify the position of the social media icons. I have simply added the raw html in the text editor section for that blog post.
I would love to do something via css only. No javascript if possible!

Hope this information helps, do let me know if am going wrong somewhere. Thanks much

Comment: what do you mean with So I want the "enter your email and singup section" to appear after the social media icons. ??? after happens what? click on icon ?

Comment: @mkad Okay so at the bottom of the page I have the enter email and sign up sections. I want both of them to appear below the social media icons

Comment: The question is when should the element appear? afte the page is loaded ? or after interaction?

Comment: @mkad oh my bad. I just want them to appear below the social media icons after page load

Comment: Use simple html.
It would make no sense to animate it after loading.

Because your site is too long and you would not see anything from the animation. 
But to answer your question: I'd solve it with javascript is the easiest way.

Comment: @mkad okay cool. Yea definitely no javascript. Just the positioning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the css solution i hope it helps!

```css
@keyframes dropemail {
      0% {
        transform: translateY(-100%);
      }
      100% {
        transform: translateY(0);
      }
    }

    #social-media-icon {
      background: yellow;
      padding: 30px;
      
      animation-name: dropemail;
      animation-iteration-count: 1;
      animation-timing-function: ease-out;
      animation-duration: 0.6s;
    }
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="social-media-icon" class="social-links rounded-share-icons">
      <a class="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fchevaun.com%2Fblog%2Fcreative-freedom%2F">
     <i class="icon fa fa-facebook"></i>
   </a>
  <a class="twitter" href="https://twitter.com/share?text=Creative+Freedom">
     <i class="icon fa fa-twitter"></i>
   </a>
  <a class="google-plus" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fchevaun.com%2Fblog%2Fcreative-freedom%2F">
     <i class="icon fa fa-google-plus"></i>
   </a>
  <a class="linkedin" href="https://linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fchevaun.com%2Fblog%2Fcreative-freedom%2F&amp;title=Creative+Freedom">
     <i class="icon fa fa-linkedin"></i>
   </a>
  <a class="tumblr" href="http://www.tumblr.com/share/link?url=http%3A%2F%2Fchevaun.com%2Fblog%2Fcreative-freedom%2F&amp;name=Creative+Freedom&amp;description=%E2%80%9CMaking+the+simple+complicated+is+commonplace%3B+making+the+complicated+simple%2C+awesomely+simple%2C+that%26%238217%3Bs+creativity.%E2%80%9D+%26%238211%3B+Charles+Mingus+%26nbsp%3B+Creativity+is+all+about+going+beyond+boundaries%2C+venturing+out+into+an+unknown+that+is+bound+by+the+endless+and+the+horizon.+It+is+the+ability+to+visualize+beyond+the+horizon%2C+with+no+norms+or+rules+to+keep%26hellip%3B">
     <i class="icon fa fa-tumblr"></i>
   </a>
  <a class="pinterest" href="https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fchevaun.com%2Fblog%2Fcreative-freedom%2F&amp;description=Creative+Freedom&amp;media=http://chevaun.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/1.jpeg">
     <i class="icon fa fa-pinterest"></i>
   </a>
      </div>
<div id="signup">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" name="EMAIL" class="required email userEmail" id="mce-EMAIL">
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="linkMain" onclick="document.forms[&quot;mc-embedded-subscribe-form&quot;].submit(); return false;">Sign Up For Beta</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: oh don't think this is what I require. See I appreciate you adding animation, but all I want is the social media icons to appear above the "enter your email and signup for beta" section.

Comment: i just edit my code. do you have any experience with html?

Comment: actually I managed to sort out this issue with a bit of handy shortcode. So yea thanks a lot for the help and sorry for the trouble